# Non-archimedean valuation and squares

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $F$ be a non-archimedean local field and $v$ the associated valuation. Is it true that there is a positive integer $n$ such that
$$v(a-1) \geq n \Longrightarrow a \in F^{\times 2}?$$

Comment: That is, are the squares in $F^{\ast}$ an open subgroup?  I believe the answer is yes, and follows from a version of Hensel's lemma.  You can find this version in Lang's ANT book.

Comment: @D_S are we even sure there's Hensel's lemma if $F$ is noncomplete and/or nondiscrete?

Comment: A local field is complete by definition.  And OP specified non-archimedean, so the valuation is discrete.

Comment: Do you impose any condition on the residue field ?